# What is Issue with <form> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

here I have created reverse string and set it to "p" tag but when I click on Button it sets value inside "p" for second and then clear it

Q:I know it's because of "form" tag but why it's happening?
**Javascript:**

```
function abc()
{
var str=document.getElementById("srcString").value; 
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML=str.split("").reverse().join("");;
}
```

**Html**

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" id="srcString" placeholder="Enter something...">
<button onClick="abc()">click</button>
<p id="ans"></p>
<form>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve on clicking the button- submit the form  or perform the abc()?

Comment: If you don't want to submit the form on clicking the button, the give the button tag an attribute 'type=button'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, the `<p>` tag is set but then the form is submited, causing your page to refresh. A fix for this is to cancel the form submit. 
**Change your code to this:**

---

## JavaScript

```
function abc() {
    var str = document.getElementById("srcString").value;
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = str.split("").reverse().join("");
    return false; //return false to cancel form submit
}
```

## HTML

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="srcString" placeholder="Enter something...">
    <button onClick="return abc()">click</button>
    <p id="ans"></p>
<form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way of avoiding the form submitting and the page reloading is setting the button `type` to `button` instead of the standard type `submit`. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/V8Gcj/1/)**

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="srcString" placeholder="Enter something..." />
    <button type="button" onClick="abc()">click</button>
    <p id="ans"></p>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since the method is GET it is just refreshing the page, try POST instead

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are reloading the page.
try returning false from your abc function to cancel submitting of the form.

Answer (score 0):

use `onsubmit="return false;"`

```
<form method="GET" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" id="srcString" placeholder="Enter something...">
<button onClick="abc()">click</button>
<p id="ans"></p>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button type property to avoid the page reloading and refreshing issue.